# Defining two different names for an activity/activity-alias

Tags: android, android-manifest, launcher

So my dilemma is that I have two versions (we'll call version A and B) of my Android application, each on different phones. The difference between them is their launching activity name.

Now, there is a third version of my app which is an upgrade to either of the two versions I described above.

Now, I understand that you should have the same launching activity name on the new version of an app if you want things to upgrade correctly (i.e. keeping the same launcher icon).

So here's the problem: I have this third version that has the same launching activity name as version A, so after the upgrade happens, the same launcher icon is used which is what I want. However, when I try to upgrade version B which uses a different launching activity name from the upgrade, it deletes the old launcher icon and puts in a new launcher icon with the updated name.

This causes at least one notable problem: take the Galaxy Note for instance. You can add folders in your app drawer. If Version B was in a folder to begin with, the upgrade would cause that launcher icon to be removed and then the new launcher icon would be added to the drawer rather with the rest of the applications than the folder.

Now is there a way to provide two names to an activity-alias so that I can solve this issue? Any other suggestions? Please and thanks! I apologize in advance if any of this was not clear. Thanks for reading!